# Доктор Лиза с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

«Доктор Лиза или доктор Лиза?» Чем аргументируется использование прописной буквы в ее должности?

Answer (score 3):

**"Доктор Лиза"** - имя собственное. Когда мы видим словосочетание **"Доктор Лиза"**, мы понимаем, что речь идет не о каком-то абстрактном враче (или человеке с докторской степенью) по имени Лиза, а о вполне конкретной **Елизавете Петровне Глинке**. Именно поэтому мы пишем слово "доктор" с большой буквы, как написали бы ее фамилию.

Чтобы было проще понять разницу в написании слова "доктор", приведу простой пример:

> Наша участковая доктор Лиза мечтает быть похожей на Доктора Лизу.